# ASP.net MVC dynamic bundling of CSS

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, bundling-and-minification

We are working on one requirement where we need to bundle CSS according to clients.

e.g. `client1` will have `style1` and `client2` will have `style2` folders and based on clients we need to bundle CSS. We can have N numbers of clients.

`/MyApp/client1` - should have style1 CSS with bundling and minification

`/myApp/client2` - should have style2 CSS with bundling and minification

from URL we are getting client ID parameter to decide which style folder needs to be load but how to achieve dynamic bundling and minification at runtime for loaded CSS?

Answer (score 0):

In addition to DynamicBundles you could easily just build client specific bundles in the bundle config but then load them on the page using razor where you check the id and load the correct bundles based on that.